# Delete an element from a certain row in an XML-type column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

Suppose I have the following:

```
CREATE TABLE tblData ( [SourceID] int, [SourceRecID] bigint, [Value] xml )
GO

INSERT INTO tblData
VALUES
( 1, 0, N'<attributes><attribute id="58" value="0" /><attribute id="86" value="1" /><attribute id="85" value="1" /><attribute id="70" value="0" /><attribute id="38" value="0" /><attribute id="68" value="0" /><attribute id="42" value="1" /><attribute id="67" value="1" /><attribute id="62" value="1" /></attributes>' ), 
( 1, 686, N'<attributes><attribute id="1" value="0.25" /><attribute id="4" value="1" /><attribute id="10" value="3" /><attribute id="11" value="1" /><attribute id="12" value="6" /></attributes>' ), 
( 1, 687, N'<attributes><attribute id="1" value="2.00" /><attribute id="2" value="60.00" /><attribute id="3" value="-1" /><attribute id="5" value="252.00" /><attribute id="6" value="0" /><attribute id="7" value="1" /><attribute id="9" value="1" /><attribute id="10" value="1" /><attribute id="11" value="2" /><attribute id="12" value="10" /></attributes>' ), 
( 1, 688, N'<attributes><attribute id="1" value="2.00" /><attribute id="2" value="60.00" /><attribute id="3" value="-1" /><attribute id="5" value="252.00" /><attribute id="6" value="0" /><attribute id="7" value="1" /><attribute id="11" value="2" /><attribute id="12" value="10" /></attributes>' )
GO

SELECT *
FROM tblData
```

Let's say I would like to delete `attribute id`=7 from the `Value` column where `SourceId` = 1, `SourceRecID` = 687.

I would expect the new value of the row SourceId = 1, SourceRecID = 687 to be:

```
N'<attributes><attribute id="1" value="2.00" /><attribute id="2" value="60.00" /><attribute id="3" value="-1" /><attribute id="5" value="252.00" /><attribute id="6" value="0" /><attribute id="9" value="1" /><attribute id="10" value="1" /><attribute id="11" value="2" /><attribute id="12" value="10" /></attributes>' ),
```

Notice that `<attribute id="7" value="1" />` is now missing from the original xml for that row.

I can't think of a way to do it...

Comment: Considering that `DELETE FROM tblData WHERE SourceID = 1;` would delete every row, why do the latter 2 requirements matter?

Comment: Are you trying to remove the entire row when that attribute ID = 7 or just remove that section from the [Value] field?

Comment: I don't want to delete the row. I just want to remove attribute id="7" from the `Value` field in that row. I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: For clarity, what would be the new value of your xml?

Comment: @Denis what you ask is possible and described in [Examples of using XQuery to update XML Data in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2738/examples-of-using-xquery-to-update-xml-data-in-sql-server/). You can use [modify](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/modify-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) with the [delete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/delete-xml-dml?view=sql-server-2017) keyword to delete nodes that match a query, eg `UPDATE HR_XML
SET Salaries.modify('delete (/Salaries/Accounting)[2]')`. I didn't know that until now by the way

Comment: @Denis in your case I think the query should be `'delete (/attributes/attribute[@id="7"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
update tblData 
set 
    Value.modify('delete (/attributes/attribute[@id="7"])')
where 
    SourceRecID = 687 and 
    SourceID = 1
```

SQL Server's XQuery contains an extension, [XML DML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-modification-language-xml-dml?view=sql-server-2017) that allows modifying XML values. Several examples are shown in [Examples of using XQuery to update XML Data in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2738/examples-of-using-xquery-to-update-xml-data-in-sql-server/).

The [modify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/modify-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) function is used to execute an XMLDML query. In that query, the [delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/delete-xml-dml?view=sql-server-2017) keyword can be used to delete all elements that match a query

Using the following script :

```
declare @tblData table ( [SourceID] int, [SourceRecID] bigint, [Value] xml );


INSERT INTO @tblData
VALUES
( 1, 0, N'<attributes><attribute id="58" value="0" /><attribute id="86" value="1" /><attribute id="85" value="1" /><attribute id="70" value="0" /><attribute id="38" value="0" /><attribute id="68" value="0" /><attribute id="42" value="1" /><attribute id="67" value="1" /><attribute id="62" value="1" /></attributes>' ), 
( 1, 686, N'<attributes><attribute id="1" value="0.25" /><attribute id="4" value="1" /><attribute id="10" value="3" /><attribute id="11" value="1" /><attribute id="12" value="6" /></attributes>' ), 
( 1, 687, N'<attributes><attribute id="1" value="2.00" /><attribute id="2" value="60.00" /><attribute id="3" value="-1" /><attribute id="5" value="252.00" /><attribute id="6" value="0" /><attribute id="7" value="1" /><attribute id="9" value="1" /><attribute id="10" value="1" /><attribute id="11" value="2" /><attribute id="12" value="10" /></attributes>' ), 
( 1, 688, N'<attributes><attribute id="1" value="2.00" /><attribute id="2" value="60.00" /><attribute id="3" value="-1" /><attribute id="5" value="252.00" /><attribute id="6" value="0" /><attribute id="7" value="1" /><attribute id="11" value="2" /><attribute id="12" value="10" /></attributes>' )
```

The contents of the row with SourceRecID 687 are :

```
<attributes>
  ...
  <attribute id="6" value="0" />
  <attribute id="7" value="1" />
  <attribute id="9" value="1" />
  ...
</attributes>
```

After executing this query :

```
update tblData 
set Value.modify('delete (/attributes/attribute[@id="7"])')
where [SourceRecID]=687 and SourceID = 1
```

The contents are :

```
...
<attribute id="5" value="252.00" />
<attribute id="6" value="0" />
<attribute id="9" value="1" />
...
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because I see you made your comment an answer. I'll mark this as the correct answer.